# If an image is using placeholder, convert to draft

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

My shop is WooCommerce. I'm currently trying to make it so that if a product in my shop is using the placeholder, it is automatically set to draft. I have also made it so this code finds the products without images, it will apply the image in $src mostly just for testing so I can see that this part is working at least. I'm not the most comfortable with PHP and the code below is a combination of other peoples suggestions and methods I have found!

I have removed the actual link below for data protection and added in a fake one. Any help is appreciated.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_placeholder_img_src', 'wp_kama_woocommerce_placeholder_img_src_filter');
function wp_kama_woocommerce_placeholder_img_src_filter($src) {
    $src = 'https://domain/location/image.png';
    $placeholder_image = get_option('woocommerce_placeholder_image', 0);
    $args = array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => - 1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'fields' => 'ids', 'meta_query' => array(array('ID' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'publish',)),);
    if (!empty($placeholder_image)) {
        if (is_numeric($placeholder_image)) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($placeholder_image, $size);
            if (!empty($image[0])) {
                $src = $image[0];
                $loop_arg = new WP_Query($args);
                $loop_ids = $loop_arg->posts;
                foreach ($loop_ids as $loop => $loop_id) {
                    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $loop_id, 'post_status' => 'publish'));
                    wp_reset_query();
                }
            }
        } else {
            $src = $placeholder_image;
            $loop_arg = new WP_Query($args);
            $loop_ids = $loop_arg->posts;
            foreach ($loop_ids as $loop => $loop_id) {
                wp_update_post(array('ID' => $loop_id, 'post_status' => 'draft'));
                wp_reset_query();
            }
        }
    }
    return $src;
}
return apply_filters('woocommerce_placeholder_img_src', $src);
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: If anyone needs it, I got this code working. This code will check my products and if it has an image, it will publish it, if not, it will draft.

```
       $args = array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => - 1, 
       'post_status' => array('publish', 'draft', 'trash'), 'fields' => 'ids');
       $loop_arg = new WP_Query($args);
       $loop_ids = $loop_arg->posts;

       foreach ($loop_ids as $loop => $loop_id) {
       wp_update_post(array('ID' => $loop_id));
       $placeholder_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($loop_id);
       if (!$placeholder_image) {
         wp_update_post(array('ID' => $loop_id, 'post_status' => 'draft'));
       } else {
         wp_update_post(array('ID' => $loop_id, 'post_status' => 'publish'));
       }
       wp_reset_query();
       }
```